# IBM Cloud: Tasks after migration of a certificate from Certificate Manager to Secrets Manager?

Tags: ibm-cloud, ibm-certificate-manager, ibm-secrets-manager

I have migrated a certificate from IBM Cloud Certificate Manager to Secrets Manager.
Now I have the same certificate in both Certificate Manager and Secrets Manager.

What should I do now to use the certificate from only Secrets Manager?

Comment: Please share more details. Is this in any way related to programming?

Answer (score 1):

IBM Cloud Certificate Manager is integrated with some IBM Cloud services. The newer IBM Cloud Secrets Manager is a more general replacement. It includes support for certificates. There is a [Certificate Manager to Secrets Manager migration guide](https://cloud.ibm.com/docs/secrets-manager?topic=secrets-manager-migrate-from-certificate-manager).

From my experience, you should

- set up notifications for expiring certificates
- test if you can benefit from automated renewal / provisioning
- check if your scenario is supported (could your app / service consume from Secrets Manager)

As stated, not all scenarios are supported right now and I use both Certificate Manager and Secrets Manager in parallel, for different sets of certificates and secrets.

Comment: Thank you for the response Henrik.

In our case we are trying to use only the newly migrated certificates which are in Secretes-Manager.

For that, how can I consume latest certificate for my service/application?

I mean How can I redirect the service/application traffic from certificate-manager to secrets-manager?

Comment: That should have been in your question. What services? Some would be to use a different API (SM instead of CM), some require reconfiguration. This list should be growing https://cloud.ibm.com/docs/secrets-manager?topic=secrets-manager-integrations

Comment: How did you use the certificate when it was stored in CM?